# How to do a numeric UNIX's sort on fields with a character attached in front of the number

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

I have a very large data (12G) that looks like this:

```
foo  r1.1   abc
foo  r10.1  pqr
qux  r2.1   lmn
bar  r33.1  xpq
```

What I want to do is to sort 2nd field numerically yielding (in reality there are more leading fields):

```
foo  r1.1   abc
qux  r2.1   lmn
foo  r10.1  pqr
bar  r33.1  xpq
```

I tried the following but won't work:

```
   sort -k1 -n
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `sort -k1.2n` if it starts with just an **r**

Comment: @Aljohs: thanks it works. Sorry, but my example is to simplified actually the field need to be sorted is not in 1st column. I have updated my example. Is there a way I can modify your approach?

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work. I tried this snippet `perl -e 'foreach $i (1,10,2,33) {print "foo\tr".$i."\.1\n";}' | sort -k2.2n`

Comment: `cat temp | sort -t $'\t' -k2.2n` works fine on my machine
But, *iff* \t is the delimiter and the field you want to be sorted by is the second one, and it starts with alpha character.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it - you need to do:

```
sort -k2
```

-k1 starts from the first character.

Comment: D'oh, sorry - just "sort -k2" gives the output you want. (Edit: well, it did before you updated the question. :)